# Fetch all tables in a particuler Postgres database using node?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres, postgresql-12

I need to fetch all tables in a particular Postgres database using node. But not finding any way to achieve that. Is there any way to get that?

For example, suppose I have a database named 'TestDatabase' it contains 4 tables( just assume it can have less or more) Person, Company, Clothes, Animal.
I need to get the name of all of them using node.

I am also using node-postgres ('pg') to connect with the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative you can use `information_schema`. It is not better then the pg_* objects in the system catalog but is standardized and more portable. Here it is:

```sql
select table_schema||'.'||table_name as table_fullname
 from information_schema."tables"
 where table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
  and table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
```

The system objects have been filtered by this expression

```sql
table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
```

You can further modify it to only include schemas that you need.

Answer (score 2):

This is a generic solution. Use the query below:

```
SELECT
   relname
FROM
   pg_class
WHERE
   relkind = 'r';
```

`pg_class` is the system catalog that holds information on table like objects. Hence the need to restrict `relkind` to 'r'. This will include all table types. To further restrict see `relpersistence` at link below.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html

Comment: I would modify your question to indicate that as it now says  'I need to fetch all tables in a particular Postgres database ...'. For what you want run the query in @Stefanov.sm answer below as the user you created the tables as. The 'information_schema` queries will only show you tables that the user running the query created or has rights to.

Comment: I do not know much above Postgres I am getting too much information by executing this ...like pg_statctics, pg_types extra. I need the only tables that I created.